# Iterate through chunks of a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have a pandas.DataFrame that looks like the following:

| Week | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City A | 100 | 300 | x | z | w |
| City B | 200 | 400 | y | q | p |
| None | None | None | None | None | None |
| **Week** | **Monday** | **Tuesday** | **Wednesday** | **Thursday** | **Friday** |
| City A | 150 | 320 | a | c | e |
| City B | 210 | 470 | z | t | q |
| City C | 260 | 446 | b | d | f |
| None | None | None | None | None | None |

This repeats until all weeks in a year are covered (it's basically a weekly calendar with data in it).

I wish to loop through the DataFrame in chunks, and do some operations with the data within those chunks.

The chunks should be basically "Week-to-Week"-high and "Week-to-Friday"-wide, if that makes sense. However, as you can see, the chunks are not equally large so I can't hard code the size to be 4x6, for example. They do, although, always go from "Week" to "Week" and go out as far to the right as "Friday".

Is there any intuitive way I can iterate through my DataFrame? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The specific way in which you will iterate over each week will depend on what you want to do with each group. Very generically, you can group by week with `groupby` as one of the answers suggests, but keep in mind that grouping by rows is generally very slow and in fact has been deprecated since pandas 2.1.

Comment: @JustLearning My goal is to take each segment, save the segment as a temporary DF, do some operations (like melt, transpose, merge, etc.) on the temporary DF and finally append/concatenate the temporary DF in a big DF which will contain all segments in the end, before moving on to the next segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df['week_index'] = df.isna().all(axis='columns').astype(int).cumsum()
for _, df_chunk in df.groupby('week_index'):
    # do something
```

To do it week-to-week:

```py
df['week_index'] = df.isna().all(axis='columns').astype(int).shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum()
for _, df_chunk in df.groupby('week_index'):
    # process each chunk
```

Comment: What is the "_" in the for loop stand for?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the week index go from Week-to-Week instead of None-to-None?

Comment: @LucasB.Bahadir check my update, I am proposing a method to it week-to-week

Answer (score 0):

Reproducing your data with the CSV file,

```
# data.csv
Week,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
City 100,300,x,z,w
City B,200,400,y,q,p
None,None,None,None,None,None
Week,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
City A,150,320,a,c,e
City B,210,470,z,t,q
City C,260,446,b,d,f
None,None,None,None,None,None
```

you can do the following in order to clean the original dataset and turn it into something more useful for groups and aggregations:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                     
                                                                                                        
# Reproduce your data, then drop NaN rows.                                                              
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)                                                               
df = df.dropna()                                                                                        
print(df, "\n")                                                                                         
                                                                                                        
# Label rows by week number, and use this label as index.                                               
df['WeekNumber'] = df[df[0] == "Week"].all(axis=1).cumsum().astype('category')                          
df = df.ffill()                                                                                         
df = df.set_index("WeekNumber")                                                                         
print(df, "\n")                                                                                         
                                                                                                        
# Regroup the dataset by week number and reuse header in each group                                     
header = list(df.iloc[0])                                                                               
df = df.groupby("WeekNumber", observed=True,                                                            
                as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[1:]).reset_index(level=0,                             
                                                                   drop=True)                           
df.columns = header                                                                                     
print(df, "\n")                                                                                         
                                                                                                        
# The name "Week" in the original dataset is somewhat inaccurate, so                                    
# change the corresponding column                                                                       
df = df.rename({"Week": "City"}, axis=1)                                                                
print(df, "\n") 

# Example
print(df.groupby("WeekNumber", observed=True).agg({"Monday": "sum"}))
```

gives

```
                Monday
WeekNumber            
1               100200
2            150210260
```